# Al actualizar una variable del scope, actualiza otra con el mismo valor Angular2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angularjs-scope

Buenas a todos.

Yo tengo un metodo que digamos que hace algo así:

```
getAll(){
         this.commonServices.getAllList()
                           .subscribe(
                               res => {
                                    this.resultList= res;
                                    this.copieResultList= res;                               
                               },
                                err => {
                                    console.log("Error: " + err);
                                });

    }
```

Hasta aquí todo bien. Llamo al servicio que me va a recuperar un array de objetos y almaceno su respuesta en dos variables del scope. `resultList`y `copieResultList`. El problema es que más abajo tengo un metodo que hace:

```
getOne(id: string){
        this.commonService.getOne(id)
                            .subscribe(
                                res => {
                                 console.log(this.resultList);
                                    this.resultList.length = 0;
                                    this.resultList= res;
                                 console.log(this.resultList);
                                },
                                err => {
                                    console.log("Prueba error: " + err);
                                });
    }
```

Aquí empieza el problema. Y es que el primer console.log me imprime la lista como es lógico. Pero el segundo no, el segundo me lo muestra vacio. Es decir al haber modificado el `resultList` me ha modificado tambien el `copieResultList`

> El scope no se está modificando por error en ningún otro lado del código.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mas que un error de Scopes, es un error de concepto de programacion. Cuando vuelcas el valor de un objeto, no vuelvas el objeto en la variable si no que creas una referencia a el, lo que explica lo que te esta pasando.

> Una vez que pasas la primera captura, ambos apuntan al mismo espacio
>   de memoria donde se encuentra dicho objeto.

Cuando llegas a la segunda imagen, modificas `resultList` pero tambien afecta a `copieResultList` porque realmente estas modificando el objeto al que ambos estan apuntando.

Comment: Entonces, ¿de qué forma puedo solucionarlo?. He entendido perfectamente lo que explicas jeje, pero no veo forma de solucionarlo.

Comment: No se la lógica de hacerlo de la forma que lo estas haciendo, me resulta raro, pero si lo necesitas puedes usar esto let nuevoObjeto = Object.assign({}, miObjeto) y obtendras una copia con diferentes referencias

Comment: Si te he resuelto la pregunta inicial, podrias marcarla como correcta? Gracias ;) @Findelias

Comment: No veo la forma de usar let aquí. Ya que si lo declaro dentro de la primera función no podría ver luego su valor en la otra. Y si lo declaro fuera de ellas más de lo mismo.

Comment: Creo que la respuesta está respondida, eso que planteas es como resolverlo en tu caso particular con ejemplos de código, para lo cual haría falta un ejemplo en plunkr donde enseñarte como se haría normalmente.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es simplemente la reputación. Toda para ti.

Comment: No es la puntuación, es ser agradecido de que te ayuden y que si tienes una pregunta, no puedes estar preguntando otra y luego otra, más que nada por claridad de los usuarios que consuman esta pregunta más tarde. Te he ofrecido la posibilidad de un plunk, fuera de SO y sin puntuaciones, para ayudarte personalmente, pero si lees el titulo de la pregunta, está respondido, y creo que estamos de acuerdo en eso. Te reitero, si preparas un plunk con tu codigo, te ayudo, si no, porque es un caso concreto, lamento no puedo hacerlo. Si no quieres mi ayuda, tambien es valido